# Equivalent of ES6 template literals in PHP?

Tags: php, string

Is there some kind of equivalent of ES6 template literals in PHP? It would look something like the following, except of course that particular piece of code doesn't work:

```
function generate_response($type, $message) {
  return "<div class='${($type === 'success') ? 'success' : 'error'}'>{$message}</div><br/>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to my knowledge but that code would work like this

```
function generate_response($type, $message) {
    $t = $type === 'success' ? 'success' : 'error';
    return "<div class='$t'>$message</div><br/>"; 
}

echo generate_response('success', 'woop de do!');
```

Comment: still no equivalent of template literals? its impossible to do something like: `$var = "${number_format($var2, 2, '.', ',')}";`??

Answer (score 1):

I've seen it done like this, with double quotes and curly brackets:

```php
$numbers = [5, 4, 8, 9, 7, 10, 25, 28];

foreach($numbers as $number) {
    echo "<p>The number is {$number}.";
}
```

Comment: Braces are not required in this code, and it does not do what the question was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I wanted to respond because it looks like nobody mentioned the `heredoc`. This is Perl and PHP (which is derived from Perl) equivalent of an ES6 template literal. The main advantage is that you can have a huge string including the proper visible indenting for code, and essential it will act like an HTML `pre` tag on the backend. With your heredoc you can have as many variable placeholders as you care to use.

### Example 1:

**Here is an example** of how [heredocs](https://carlalexander.ca/php-string-formatting/) are used:

> Heredoc lets you do something that’s harder to do with a quoted string literal. It lets you define a block of text as a literal. Here’s an a small example:

```
$version = PHP_VERSION;
echo <<<EOT
Current PHP version: $version
EOT;
```

> <<< is the heredoc operator. It’s what tells PHP that the block of text below is a literal. EOT is the identifier that PHP will look for to close off the block of text.

### Example 2:

Here is an little more detailed example that I created as a demo:

```
$date = date('F d, Y');

$time_frame = 10;

$customer = array(
    "name" => "Fred Flintstone",
    "occupation" => "Quarry Worker",
    "add_city" => "Bedrock",
    "timezone" => "Prehistory"
);

$html = <<<EOT
<p style='color: red; font-weight: bold;'>$date</p>
<hr>

Customer Name: {$customer['name']}<br>
Occupation: {$customer['occupation']}<br>
City: {$customer['add_city']}<br>

<pre>Dear Mr. {$customer['name']},

Please examine the attached invoice and let us know within
$time_frame days whether you have any questions about
the charges.

Sincerely,

ACME Corp
EOT;

echo $html;
```

#### RESOURCES:

- https://andy-carter.com/blog/what-are-php-heredoc-nowdoc

Comment: The value of the ES6 template string is that you can execute arbitrary code in it. There is no equivalent structure in PHP, which only allows for variable interpolation.

Comment: Yes, heredocs in PHP would be the go to.  I wrote an ancient article on this 20(!) years ago : https://web.archive.org/web/20030422120416/http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2003/04/10/php_heredocs.html